# Who decided that segwit2x isn't going to happen?

Tags: segwit2x

I have read this article:

https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-segwit2x/2017-November/000685.html

Since bitcoin is a decentralized system, who's decided that segwit2x isn't going to be deployed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key proponents of the New York Agreement have rescinded their support after large parts of the community opposed their initiative for months. Theoretically, a miner could still activate the fork unilaterally, but the expected value of the Segwit2x network dropped significantly with the exit of said key proponents.

Answer (score 3):

Though its major proponents have called it off, there's a miner with an unknown (likely less than 10%) amount of hash power vowing to continue: https://cointelegraph.com/news/segwit-death-challenge-bitpico-vows-to-fork-as-bitcoincom-goes-100-bitcoin-cash

You can monitor miners who are signaling for Segwit2x by looking at the coinbase of blocks here: https://coin.dance/blocks#blockDetails